# How to synchronize parametrization across pytest fixtures?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, code-organization

I have two fixtures `A` and `B` with the same `params` argument passed to `pytest.fixture()`. Additionally, `B` takes `A` as an argument:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def A(request):
    if request.param == 1:
        # do stuff to get matrix_1
        return matrix_1
    if request.param == 2:
        # do stuff to get matrix_2
        return matrix_2

@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def B(request, A):
    if request.param == 1:
        # do stuff with A to get matrix_3
        return matrix_3
    if request.param == 2:
        # do stuff with A to get matrix_4
        return matrix_4
```

I also have a function `test_method`, which takes fixtures `B` and `my_class` (a fixture that returns a `MyClass()` instance) as arguments and tests a method of `my_class`. The method takes `B` as an argument. I don't think this information necessarily matters for the question, it is just here for context:

```py
from my_module import MyClass

@pytest.fixture
def my_class():
    return MyClass()

def test_method(my_class, B):
    # do stuff to get the expected value
    actual = my_class.method(B)
    assert actual == expected
```

The problem is that the whole construct only makes sense if `A` and `B` have the same params at every point in time, i.e. `A` cannot have `request.param = 1`, when `B` has `request.param = 2`. These variables are not intended to be used otherwise in the program, and the tested code breaks if they are.

Is there a way to share, or synchronize parametrization across fixtures? Or redesign the code somehow, so that it's not a problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Updated after the comments by the OP*:

In your code, you create four tests instead of two, two of them identical. You can use a base fixture that just provides the parameters and not parameterize the derived fixtures instead:

```py
@pytest.fixture(params=[1, 2])
def Base(request):
    return request.param

@pytest.fixture
def A(Base):
    if Base == 1:
        return value_1
    if Base == 2:
        return value_2


@pytest.fixture
def B(Base):
    if Base == 1:
        return value_3
    if Base == 2:
        return value_4
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that A does not return a scalar value, but a complicated matrix (I should have been more clear about that). If I have to test A for equality to matrices inside B that kind of defeats the purpose of A. I will correct the question to reflect A is not a scalar value. I guess I can try to make A into a class, that has request.param as one of its attributes (which can be tested for equality inside B), but I was hoping for a more elegant solution

Comment: I guess another way to approach this would be to define A and B within the same fixture and return as a list or something. But that's is also sort of ineligant

Comment: Maybe I can add another fixture, C, that returns request.param values and acts as an argument in A and B instead of the @pytest.fixture(params=...)?

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer accordingly. Your last proposition is the best one.